# Android Println() to a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I would like to take some variables, listed here;

```
double dBench = (((Math.floor((dWeight*.664)/10))*10)-10)+dPush;
double dFlies = (dBench)*.6;
double dCurls = (dWeight*dPull)*.25;
double dLats = ((Math.floor((dWeight*.5)/10))*10);

System.out.println(dBench);
System.out.println(dFlies);
System.out.println(dCurls);
System.out.println(dLats);
```

But how do I get the println()'s to print to a textview or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to do println to textview. TextView has method called **setText** and **getText**. setText can set text to TextView and getText can get text from textview. [Look here for more info.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

[Android Tutorial for TextView](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/android-button-textview-example.html)

For double,

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(Your double value));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the textview's set text method

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText("This text will be placed in the textView");
```

For a double value it will look like this

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(double_variable);
```

Comment: (Upvote) Please add an example of properly displaying a `double` in a `TextView`.

Comment: Or as a shortcut for using a double you could do `textView.setText(""+double_variable)` Just a shortcut :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to print a value in textView:

```
TextiView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
textView.setText(...see below...);
```

Integer: Integer.valueOf(integerVariable).toString()
the same can be done with Long, Double etc. Here is analogic example for Double:

```
double a = some value;
String toShow = Double.valueOf(a).toString();
textView.setText(toShow);
```

If you want to check those values (debug) you can use Log class.
Log.d("VALUE", Integer.valueOf(integerVariable).toString());
In this case the value will be shown in LogCat (tag VALUE). You can filter messages typing tag:VALUE

Integer, Long, Double are wrapper classes for primitives and those classes have toString() method which you can use to pass String into the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the value which is stored into variables you can use log cat commands to print them into console as follows:

```
Log.v("Title" , variable_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

or for numeric value you can use

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText(""+Your double value);
```